# Null pointer exception after checking for not null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

I have a strange java.lang.NullPointerException on a variable that should not be null.

```
Object[] params = new Object[10];
if (param1 != null)
    params[0] = param1;
```

param1 is given as a method parameter, and it can be null.
Normally, when affecting param1 to params[0], it is not null (otherwise it won't pass the if statement).

Here is the error (line 144 is "params[0] = param1;"):

```
Exception in thread "Jalen Agent" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jalen.MethodStats.onMethodEntry(MethodStats.java:144)
    at hanoi.TowersOfHanoi.solveHanoi(TowersOfHanoi.java)
    at hanoi.TowersOfHanoi.main(TowersOfHanoi.java:29)
```

Here is the full code of the method where the exception occurs:

```
public static void onMethodEntry(int id, String className, String methodName, Object param1, Object param2, Object param3, Object param4, Object param5) {
    synchronized (globalLock) {
        Object[] params = new Object[10];
        if (param1 != null)
            params[0] = param1;
        if (param2 != null)
            params[1] = param2;
        if (param3 != null)
            params[2] = param3;
        if (param4 != null)
            params[3] = param4;
        if (param5 != null)
            params[4] = param5;
        MethodStats.onMethodEntry(id, className, methodName, params);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

To clarify my example, I am in a context of:

1. Instrument a Java application using ASM
2. Run the new instrumented classes while using a Java agent
3. The agent will use information collected by the instrumented code to run some measurements
4. The agent also collects the values of methods' parameters of the application.

For this, onMethodEntry is executed on each method run. I have several of these methods with different signatures. In particular:

```
public static void onMethodEntry(int id, String className, String methodName, Object[] params) {
    synchronized (globalLock) {
        StringBuilder fullMethodName = new StringBuilder(className).append('.').append(methodName).append('-').append(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        MethodStats.addNewMethod(id, fullMethodName.toString());
        System.out.println(fullMethodName.toString() + " -- " + id);
        for (Object param : params) {
            if (param != null)
                System.out.println("Param: " + param.toString());
        }
        startTimes[depth] = System.nanoTime();
        stack[depth++] = MethodStats.getMethodInfo(id);
    }
}

public static void onMethodEntry(int id, String className, String methodName, Object param1) {
    synchronized (globalLock) {
        Object[] params = new Object[10];
        if (param1 != null)
            params[0] = param1;
        MethodStats.onMethodEntry(id, className, methodName, params);
    }
}

public static void onMethodEntry(int id, String className, String methodName, Object param1, Object param2) {
    synchronized (globalLock) {
        Object[] params = new Object[10];
        if (param1 != null)
            params[0] = param1;
        if (param2 != null)
            params[1] = param2;
        MethodStats.onMethodEntry(id, className, methodName, params);
    }
}
```

And this is the code I used for instrumenting the program classes (i.e. Tower of Hanoi):

```
public void visitCode() {
    mv.visitLdcInsn(new Integer(this.methodID));
    this.visitLdcInsn(this.className);
    this.visitLdcInsn(this.methodName);
    String paramCall = "";
    if (this.numParam > 0) {
        // Load parameters
        for (int i=1; i<=this.numParam; i++) {
            this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, i);
            paramCall += "Ljava/lang/Object;";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(paramCall);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC,
            "jalen/MethodStats",
            "onMethodEntry",
            "(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;" + paramCall + ")V");
    super.visitCode();
}
```

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that the NPE would occur in `params[0] = param1`. Could you come up with a minimal complete example that demonstrates this and that we can experiment with?

Comment: It is also worth noting that the `if`s are completely redundant.

Comment: Why the object array size is not 5 but 10?

Comment: Yes, NPE is right -- which value should `params[0]` have if `param1` *is* `null`?

Comment: Yes, removing the ifs should not change semantics of this code.

Comment: Homeworks (Towers of hanoi) are for self solving, not realy appropriate

Comment: Towers of hanoi is just an example to check whether my code (which is a Java agent) is working correctly.
Concretely, I am instrumenting the bytecode of an application (i.e., towers of hanoi), and using a java agent to get the value of methods' parameters. Hence, the list of parameters (which I support up until 10, in different methods. Here I showed just one).

Comment: According to the stacktrace the NPE is in `MethodStats.onMethodEntry` and not in the code you pasted.

Comment: I'll be posting a minimal code with the error soon.

Comment: is it possible to pass a array of size 10 and catch it in 5 different objects? I mean. I dont see how your line ` MethodStats.onMethodEntry(id, className, methodName, params);`

Comment: Yep NPE, ifs are redundant here. Nevertheless, removing them doesn't change the exception thrown at the same line.

Comment: You should ensure that you get the line on which the NPE occurs right. I'm 90% certain that it is not at the line you say it is. The only way `foo[0] = bar;` can throw a NPE is if `foo == null`. And you initialized `params` basically on the row above the line where you claim the NPE occurs. Re-check that it really is this line that is causing the problem.

Comment: Alderath, I also though this. I will be trying to debug the error more. Mainly, I am manipulating bytecode with my instrumentation (using ASM), so maybe things got messed up with the exception.

Answer (score 5):

First, the error is *not* on the `params[0] = param1` line, because the stack trace shows that your code entered the `onMethodEntry` method.

There is absolutely no point in adding `if` statements: in case `param1` is `null`, there would be no `null` assignment, but `params[0]` would *remain* `null` because all unassigned positions in `new Object[10]` are initially set to `null`.

In order to fix the problem, you should first figure out what objects must be placed in the array instead of `null` parameters, and then modify the conditions as follows:

```
if (param1 != null) {
    params[0] = param1;
} else {
    params[0] = // something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insights. The idea of the assignment is to run get the list of values of methods' parameters. I see that the ifs are unnecessary here, still the exception is thrown at 'params[0] = param1' (there is more than one 'onMethodEntry' methods, see my edits up).

Comment: He could as weell `new Object[] {param1, param2, param3, param4, param5}`

Comment: *IF* the "params[0] = param1" is the line with the null pointer, then the only thing that could be wrong is that "params" is not initialized.  You have put up a code fragment that seemingly cannot produce the error you report, in such a way that those of us trying to help you cannot verify the most basic facts about your problem.  Put another way, you have reached a partial conclusion and given us that as a starting point.  The good bet is that the problem is not exhibited by what you have shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace your

```
onMethodEntry(int id, String className, String methodName, Object[] params) {
```

method with the **varargs** version:

```
onMethodEntry(int id, String className, String methodName, Object... params) {
```

That way, you can get rid of your other methods, which are all the same, just with different amount of parameters. Also the method containing your error would disappear. If the error still persists, you're one step closer to finding it.
Also, you wouldn't have to change any code where you call the method, because it's signature is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I initially used varargs, but ASM does't seem to like it much (it throws that it can't find the method with X params). This is why I used multiple methods with different parameters size.